# "Pure Energy" in special relativity and why does the rest energy follow from a derivation at the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light, mass-energy

I'm currently studying special relativity by reading through the [lecture notes of M. Fowler](https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/252/relativistic_mass.html) from the University of Virginia.

The famous equation $E=mc^2$ is derived by analyzing the work done by a force acting upon a particle that is moving at close to the speed of light. However, the equation is most often said to describe the amount of energy inherent to a particle at rest with rest mass $m_0$. At the moment I don't get how this statement can result from a derivation in which a particle has a speed of $c$ (which to me seems more or less like the opposite of being at rest).

I tried finding a plausible logical connection and came across the [statement](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/einstein/lrk-hand-emc2expl.html#:%7E:text=%22Energy%20equals%20mass%20times%20the,become%20mass%2C%20and%20vice%20versa.) that if we were to convert the rest mass of an object into "pure" energy it would *by definition* be in the form of electromagnetic radiation. Since I was not quite satisfied with this answer, I tried reading up on that and it seems as if the concept of "pure" energy is basically nonsense and that photons definitely are not pure energy since they possess a variety of other physical quantities besides energy. So how could it logically be explained that the equation following from a derivation analyzing a particle at the speed of light actually describes the energy of an object at rest?

Comment: If you want to understand  $ E=mc2$, you should read a textbook on relativity and forget what is written in the web pages you linked. Not only is "pure energy" a couple of words with no meaning in physics, but the whole description of the relation between energy and mass is flawed.

Comment: Light beam is not energy, and walnut is not mass. Energy, just as mass, is a property of a physical system. There is no such thing as "pure energy" in physics, this is a word group from mysticism/pseudoscience, and now apparently, also used in bad popular science media outlets. Unfortunately this level of sloppy language and borderline deceptive descriptions is quite common in mainstream media production on physics. Don't waste your time with it, study well established textbooks and papers instead.

Answer (score 4):

As a consequence of the postulates of special relativity, it can be shown that the total energy possessed by a moving object is:

$$E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac v c\right)^2}}=\gamma~ mc^2$$

If we express this using a series expansion, we find:

$$E= mc^2 \left[ 1+ \frac 1 2 \left(\frac v c\right)^2 + \frac 3 8 \left(\frac v c\right)^4 +...\right] $$

This is true for any object with mass $m$, traveling at speed $v$, including $v=0$.  It can be seen that the second term $\frac 1 2 mv^2$ is the classical kinetic energy in Newtonian mechanics.  The additional terms to the right of this are insignificant for small fractions of lightspeed, so Newton's formula is a good approximation in most cases.

Looking at the first term, $mc^2$ this is the energy we get when velocity is zero, known as the "rest energy." The object has this energy simply by virtue of having its mass $m$, irrespective of any state of motion.

This derivation results from considering a moving object at speed $v$, which can be any number including arbitrarily close to zero. So it is not necessary to consider speeds close to light speed to obtain the result.

Because only differences in energy have physically measureable effects, Newtonian mechanics worked without the $mc^2$ term, because as the mass of moving objects never changed (detectably), this rest energy never contributed to anything. It *does* contribute when we consider processes that involve light being emitted or absorbed by matter, because matter has mass and light does not. These types of physical experiments were beginning to be studied in the time that Special Relativity was developed. For example, when a radioactive metal decays and releases gamma rays, those rays carry away energy that can be detected, heating up other objects, etc. That emitted energy "comes from" the rest energy $mc^2$ of the metal, and its mass decreases as a result.

Comment: Thank you very much! So basically the derivation chosen to introduce $E=mc^2$ in the literature I referenced is probably not the ideal one. Can you recommend a book or source which introduces the equation in the way you did in your answer?

Comment: Honestly Einstein's original paper is pretty accessible.  https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/specrel.pdf. In Section 10 he derives the Kinetic Energy of an electrically charged particle, which can be generalized to any particle.